# GLX manual pages under OS X

Tags: macos, opengl, x11, glx, manpage

I am running OS X 10.11 and am doing some X11 OpenGL programming. I can access X11 man pages as well as OpenGL man pages using commands like this:

```
man XCreateWindow
man glVertex
```

However, when I try to access man pages for GLX, nothing comes up. I have tried the following format:

```
man glXQueryVersion
man glXIntro
```

I have tried to find the GLX man pages on my system using the following command but they didn't come up:

```
find /  -iname '*glxqueryversion*'
```

Does OS X have man pages for GLX? If so, how can I access them? If not, what are my options? (One, of course, is reading GLX man pages from sites like https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/#glX however I would prefer to use man pages on my system on principle, because local man pages are more likely to be correlated with the capabilities my system actually has.)